# Maven can't recognize the dependencies in both local and server

Tags: maven, build

The dependencies already be available in both local and server, but maven build(clean, install) still failed and complain that can't find them.

1> Although the dependency can be found in server, but failed to build online

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/aspectj-maven-plugin/1.4/aspectj-maven-plugin-1.4.pom
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:pom:1.4' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2%29:) Authorization failed: Access denied to: h
ttp://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/aspectj-maven-plugin/1.4/aspectj-maven-plugin-1.4.pom
```

2> I try to try offline, as the dependency is already in local, but failed

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

GroupId: org.codehaus.mojo
ArtifactId: aspectj-maven-plugin
Version: 1.4

Reason: System is offline.

  org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:pom:1.4
```

3> BTW, i have configured the relevant profile for the server

Answer (score 0):

1. You're likely behind a proxy that needs authentication.
2. To run Maven in offline mode do `mvn -o clean install`

Comment: Yes, the server is behind a proxy and already configured it in the setting.xml, but maven still complain can't find it.